# Bulk Upload PDF Forms to AEM Repository

Tags: adobe, aem

We recently began using Adobe LiveCycle and Adobe Experience Manager. We're not using AEM for our web site, however. We're just wanting to use the Forms Portal portion of it to allow us to organize our forms, tag them, etc, then provide a searchable interface.

We have several hundred pre-AEM/LiveCycle PDF forms. Rather than manually uploading one PDF file at a time, we would like to do a bulk upload into the repository.

If I remember correctly, I saw someone do this using CRXDE Lite, navigating to /content/dam/formsanddocuments, then dragging the documents in. However, when I try that, it just opens up Acrobat Reader to display the PDF.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about drag/drop in the browser (never tried it), but there are a couple of methods you could use:

#### Curl / Bash

If you're happy scripting this in Bash, one method is to use curl to upload the file, along the lines of:

```
curl -F"./*=@form1.pdf" \ 
     -F"./*@TypeHint=nt:file" \
http://admin:admin@localhost:4502/content/dam/forms/form1
```

For example, you could create a script to loop over all the PDFs in your directory & upload them one at a time.

#### VLT

Another option would be to add create a [content package with Maven](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/dev-tools/vlt-mavenplugin.html), build it and install via CRX Package Manager.

Or you could use the [Filevault (VLT) tool that Adobe provide](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/dev-tools/ht-vlttool.html) as a VCS-style link between your file system & the repository — checkout to a directory, add the PDFs in and then do a `vlt add; vlt ci` to push them back into AEM.

#### WebDav

AEM supports [mounting the repository via WebDav](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/content/webdav-access.html), so that you could drag the files in using Finder/Explorer.

It can be slow, but if you're just doing a one-off dump of files into AEM, it could be an option.